# Vaadin & Shiro navigation

Tags: vaadin, shiro

I use shiro-vaadin-integration plugin

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "Test", asyncSupported = true,
    initParams = @WebInitParam(name = Constants.I18N_PROVIDER,
        value = "com.test.TranslationProvider"))
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false)
@Slf4j
public class AppServlet extends VaadinServlet {

  @Override
  protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
    log.info("Init Shiro");
    IniRealm iniRealm = new IniRealm("classpath:shiro.ini");
    DefaultSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager(iniRealm);
    // SessionDAO sessionDAO = new MemorySessionDAO();
    // ((DefaultSessionManager) securityManager.getSessionManager()).setSessionDAO(sessionDAO);
    // securityManager.setCacheManager(new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager());
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    log.info("Finish Init Shiro");

    super.servletInitialized();
  }
```

The crux of the problem is that after logging in. I throws on the main page.

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()
```

Return true.

Further, when trying to navigate in the application.

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()
```

Return false.

It feels like a session lasts a couple of seconds

shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /signin
vaadin = org.vaadin.shiro.VaadinNavigationRolesAuthorizationFilter
vaadin.loginUrl = /signin

[users]
admin@admin.com = 1@QWaszx, admin
user = user, user

[roles]
admin = *
user = action1:*

[urls]
/ = anon, vaadin
/signin = anon, vaadin
/signup = anon, vaadin
/forgot-password = anon, vaadin
/reset-password = anon, vaadin
/registration-complete = anon, vaadin
/create-account = anon, vaadin
/payment = anon, vaadin
/environment = authc, vaadin[admin]
/billing = authc, vaadin[admin]
/settings = authc, vaadin[admin]
```

If we follow the link quickly after authorization, it will pass.
And if you wait for the application falls

Comment: What vaadin version? Is your url changing as defined in the [urls] section?

Comment: Vaadin 12.0.7 Yes url change from localhost:8080/environment to localhost:8080/billing

Comment: I have my doubt, that an url based approach will work.  The URLs there are just JS History based namings in the client and are used to navigate as part of the state.  They usually don't get sent to the server for requests.